# How to list ArrayFilter?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to count the number of consecutive natural numbers for a list of natural numbers.

For example
If {1,2,3,7,9,10,15} then Length @ {1,2,3} = 3 & Length @ {9,10} = 2  and so I should get {{1,2,3},{9,10}} or {3,2} as a result.

However, the result is not shown because the following command is used.

```
test = {1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 10, 15}; Gather [test, # 1 + 1 == # 2 &]
```

However, this result is as follows. {{1, 2}, {3}, {7}, {9, 10}, {15}}

I want to ask how to fix it. How to list ArrayFilter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst = {1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 10, 15}
SequenceCases[Differences@lst, {p : Repeated[1]} :> 1 + Length[{p}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
split = Select[Split[test, #1 + 1 == #2 &], Length@# > 1 &]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {9, 10}}

```
Length /@ split
```

> {3, 2}